# Binding objective-c library to Xamarin Project using Objective Sharpie

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am developing an iOS application using Xamarin Studio. The application is going to work with [Infinite Peripherals Linea Pro 5](http://ipcprint.com/ios-peripherals/linea-pro-5.html) (a barcode scanner that you attache to an iPod/iPhone).
The Linea SDK provided by Infinite Peripherals is an objective-c library with an associated header file. I've followed [Xamarins iOS binding tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough), skipping the first parts and starting at chapter **"3.2. Create a Xamarin.iOS Binding Project"** (since I already have the fat binary file).
I have installed Objective Sharpie v0.4.11 and the Xcode Command Line Tools.
When I try to create the binding using Objective Sharpie I get the following error message:

[image: Objective Sharpie error msg]

After some research I find that this probably is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13188) caused by Objective Sharpie, but is there any way around this bug? I really need to get this library in to my MonoTouch project.

P.S.
I have also checked out [the tutorial by David Sandor](http://davidsandor.com/?tag=/LineaSDK), but it is really outdated and I do not possess enough knowledge to update it.

Answer (score 4):

If Objective-Sharpie doesn't work for your project, you can:

- Do a manual binding, or build upon David Sandor's one. That's not *that* hard.
- Try to find the offending part of the header file, by removing part of it and process it with Obj-Sharpie (the header file is not that long, once you strip the comments away)

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do a manual binding. Figured this probably is the best solution in my case.

Comment: there's a binding for lineaPro at https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/LineaPRO

Comment: I was recommended this github project on another question of mine, and it works perfect! I even added the newest Linea library file and it still worked.