# Xamarin binding objective-c library to C# delegates and events

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

This is a follow up from my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329500/binding-objective-c-library-to-xamarin-project-using-objective-sharpie) about binding objective-c library to xamarin project.
So I figured that I will create the api definition my self, but I cannot figure out how to rewrite objective-c delegates to C# delegates/events. I've come to the understanding that objective-c delegates is not the same as C# delegates, but more like C# events.

This is the objective-c delegate definition (from the header file):

```
@protocol LineaDelegate
@optional

-(void)connectionState:(int)state;

@end
```

This is the objective-c class definition (from the header file):

```
@interface Linea : NSObject

-(void)connect;

@end
```

The connect method works in background and will notify the caller of connection success via connectionState delegate.

Now, how do I bind the api correctly? This is my ApiDefinition.cs so far:

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface Linea{
     [Export ("isPresent")]
     bool IsPresent();

     //the delegate that will be notified of Linea events
     [Export("addDelegate:")]
     void AddDelegate (NSObject newDelegate);

     [Export("connect")]
     void Connect ();
}
```

How can I convert the objective-c delegate into something useful in Xamarin studio and C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now, the minute I post a question here I figure out the solution by my self... I post the solution here  not only for my own reference, but also for others out there who will struggle with the same issue.

I found [this tutorial (see chapter 4.3)](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events) and figured I had to use weak delegates. 
Working like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to bind the LineaSDK, luckily for you, a full binding is already available:

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/LineaPRO

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried so to find something like this.